# Can I store a mapped drive's contents on an external drive?

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

I'm pretty sure this is not possible, but I want to ask the experts before employing other options.

Basically, I have:

```
Host:   Computer -> C:\
                    D:\Folder (external drive)
Client: Computer -> C:\
                    D:\Folder (external drive)
```

Is there a way to `Map Network Drive` from `Host -> D:\Folder (external drive)` to `Client -> D:\Folder (external drive)` using symlinks or anything else?

I expect not, and am anticipating the use of a third-party sync program. But I'd rather do this natively if possible.

Comment: does client D:\ already exist, or have files in it? does it have a reason to exist? because it seems like you could just share the folder from host via network share and just map network drive to D:\ on client.

Comment: Great question @Nalaurien. The issue is space. I was considering mapping the host's `D:\Folder` to the client, then making that mapped drive "Always available offline" so the files would be synced. But the client's `C:` doesn't have enough space for all the files in the host's `D:\Folder` - that's why the client's `D:\Folder` is on an external drive.